# Laravel CSRF Token Mismatch For 1 User

Tags: laravel, csrf, csrf-protection

I have a small application that has a handful of authenticated users. One of the users is trying to login and they keep getting a token mismatch when trying to log in. No other user on the platform is experiencing problems and I cannot seem to replicate it. I've had them clear their cookies and cache and it didn't solve the issue.

Any other thoughts on what may be causing it for this individual user?

Comment: (long shot) what browser are they using ?

Comment: Internet Explorer is what was sent to me in the screenshot. He did say he tried multiple computers but I'm not sure if he tried multiple browsers.

Comment: here  is a similar post: [Laravel 5 and Internet Explorer : Token Mismatch](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30907900/laravel-5-and-internet-explorer-token-mismatch). Perhaps it is also the server time :/

Comment: Thanks for the link to the other question. I checked the server time and it is set to the correct time and also matches the timezone set in the Laravel App config file. I also tested in IE on one of my machines and it worked correctly.

Comment: I have confirmed with the user that the problem only exists in IE, with Chrome it works correctly.